# NetBeans - Run JavaFx tests with command-line arguments

Tags: javafx, netbeans, junit

In NetBeans -> Project properties -> Actions -> Run project - I can setup runfx.args property with command-line arguments and in runtime, application can see them. I didn't find a way to do the same for tests (Test file, Test project actions). Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with maven and surefire plugin. Arguments are passed to tests as system properties. Surefire configuration looks like this:

```
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <systemProperties>
              <property>
                <name>argName</name>
                <value>argValue</value>
              </property>
            </systemProperties>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```